# Is it support to use Infrared radiation module in ESP12E?

Tags: esp8266, ir

[image]

I have a IR module -->image as shown

is it possible to use the IR module in esp8266?

how to do(sent and receive)?

what is the packet format of IR module?

please explain.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to use the IR module in esp8266?

Yes.

> how to do(sent and recive)?

You send by pressing a button on your remote control. You receive by measuring the timing of the changes in the pin state.

> what is the packet format of IR module?

Whatever packet format your remote control sends.

It's no different using IR on an ESP8266 compared to an Arduino. There's a library that everyone uses (IRRemote.h), and there are plenty of examples and tutorials on the web (or on YouTube if you can't be bothered to read). I suggest you ask Google for some.